# Saving a copy of incoming mail for specific recipient in Exim

Tags: linux, debian, exim, filtering

I need to archive important mail incoming for specific address in case it gets accidentally deleted from email server, etc.

Either saving or using a pipe to archive it on backup machine is fine (I can `rsync` the backup automatically later, etc).

However, I have trouble to get `system_filter` working. I have configured it this way so far:

`/etc/exim4/exim4.conf`:

```
system_filter = /etc/exim4/system_filter
system_filter_user = Debian-exim
system_filter_group = Debian-exim

system_filter_directory_transport = local_copy_to_directory

# transport section

local_copy_to_directory:
    driver = appendfile
    delivery_date_add
    envelope_to_add
    return_path_add
    group = Debian-exim
    user = Debian-exim
    mode = 0660
    maildir_format = true
    create_directory = true
```

In `/etc/exim4/system_filter`:

```
# Exim filter
if $local_part is "example"
then
    unseen save /tmp/example_dir
endif
```

Nothing gets written in logs, nothing gets saved (normal delivery occurs of course).

When I change `$local_part` in system filter file to `root` and test it like so:

```
% exim  -bF /etc/exim4/system_filter -d-all+filter -f sender@example.com  <tfpmet 
Exim version 4.89 uid=0 gid=0 pid=1261 D=200
...
Return-path taken from "Return-path:" header line
Return-path = ex2@ex2.com
Sender      = sender@example.com
Recipient   = root@localdomain.com
Testing Exim filter file "/etc/exim4/system_filter"

Condition is true: $local_part is root
Unseen save message to: /tmp/example_dir
Filtering did not set up a significant delivery.
Normal delivery will occur.
  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Exim pid=1261 terminating with rc=0 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

It clearly says:

```
Condition is true: $local_part is root
Unseen save message to: /tmp/example_dir
```

However, nothing gets saved again.

OS: Debian 9.11 amd64.

I'd prefer to achieve this result using system filter, but any good solution would do really.

Answer (score -1):

It might not be the most elegant of solutions, but 'procmail' can do that. In the .procmail file for that user you create a copy:

```
:0 c
/var/mail/backup_file
```